# How to access the one of the chained functions in a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, chaining, jquery-chaining

How can I access the one of the chained functions in a plugin?

this is my plugin, in which I need to return an appended element on the document.

```
(function($){

        $.fn.extend({ 

            selection: function(options) {

                var defaults = {
                    element:     "selection"
                }

                var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
                var o = options;

                var $this = this;


               $this.function_1 = function(object)
                {
                    alert('function 1');

                }

                $this.function_2 = function(object)
                {
                    alert('function 2');
                }

                $(document.body).append("<div class='element'>Loading</div>");

                var element = $('.element');

                return element;

            }
        });

    })(jQuery);​
```

It should alerts 'function 2' when the button is clicked but it returns error on firefox.

Below is my jsffiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/dm3ft/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to add an argument to the plugin function to pass method as string. Basics are taken from [jQuery plugin authoring docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
(function($) {

    var methods = {
        function_1: function(object) {
            alert('function 1');
        },
        function_2: function(object) {
            alert('function 2');
        }
    };


$.fn.selection = function(method, options) {

    return this.each(function(){

        $(this).click(function() {

              // Method calling logic
               if (methods[method]) {
                   return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
               } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
                   return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
               } else {
                   $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip');
               }
          });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Then to call plugin method:

```
  $('.chain-function').selection('function_2'/* optional options object*/);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dm3ft/1/

NOTE: It is important that you realize that `this` inside the plugin function is the DOM element and not confuse it with `this` being part of your class

Comment: thank you. the problem in my plugin is that there is not `click` or each `event`...

Comment: `click` I understand...I just used `click` since link said "clcik here". `each` is used to loop over full collection of elements assuming you call plugin on selector that has multiple elements in DOM. If you don't want `click`, remove it and just use the code within the handler

Comment: `each` will not matter (or fail) if there is only one element in collection

Comment: Thanks. how do I return the appended element then with `each`?

Comment: please be more specific with questions. I don't know what you mean. `return this.each` allows chaining of other jQuery methods

Comment: also asking about appended elements but only code you've shown does an alert and that's all

Comment: just remember `this` inside the `each` is the individual DOM element, `this` inside the plugin not inside `each`, is the whole collection of elements

Comment: I am quite confused with these two `this` to be honest. will think it through anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **jQuery.fn**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.chain-function').function_2();

});

(function($){

    $.fn.function_2 = function(object){

        alert("yay!");
        var element = $("<div />").addClass("element").text("Loading");
        element.appendTo(  $(document.body) );
        return element;

    };

})(jQuery);​
```